# Pokemon Go egg distance to hatch

Tags: pokemon-go

I was trying to figure out what the convention rate of the distance you travel in real life to the distance in the game I have been in a car with that app opened and gone almost 100 miles and yet it says on there I have only moves 4.6km if this is so what is the point of eggs why not say it is almost impossible to hatch the egg your waisting your time and gas

Answer (score 0):

The game has systems in place so that driving cars and biking quickly prevent you from "cheating" and getting your egg to hatch faster than it would while actually actual walking. The ratio of kilometers in real life to the game is 1:1.